# “invalid operands to binary expression” error?

Tags: c++

C++ newbie here, basically I am trying to print out a list of random characters based off user input. I know my error involves the "m <= num" statement, but not sure how to go about fixing that. Or am I going about this completely wrong? Explanations are greatly appreciated!

**Note** My logic is that 'm' is the list of characters so for 'num'  I am trying to print out a list of characters based on the value of 'num'. For example if the user selects 2 for list and 5 for elements I would want the output to be....
list 1: "wtwef" 
list 2: "wopoe"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  srand (time(NULL));
  int L;

  string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  list<string> m;

  cout << "Give the number of lists: ";
  cin >> L;

  for (int i = 1; i <= L; i++){
    cout << "Give the number of elements for list " << L << " : "<< endl;
    int num; cin >> num;

    for (int k = 0; m <= num; k++){
      cout << alpha[rand() %100] << " " << endl;
      m.push_back(alpha[rand() %100]);

}

  cout << "Give a word: " << endl;
  cin >> s;

  }
```

Comment: `m` is obviously a `list<string>`. You declare it like that.. `n` is an `int`. You can't compare a `list` with an `int`. What do you expect to accomplish by that? What does that mean to you, comparing a list of strings with an integer?

Comment: Why are you comparing an int with a list of strings?

Comment: Sorry! I just updated the question to explain my thought process.

Comment: Your thought process doesn't really explain what do you expect to happen by comparing a `list<string>` with an `int`. The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming states the following: your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. You told your computer: compare a `list<string>` with an `int`. Your computer replies: LOL! Can't do that. That is the explanation for the error message. In C++ you cannot compare a `list<string>` with an `int`. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: I think you are trying to do either k <= num or m.size() <= num. But a better solution is to use something like back_inserter.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the expression "m <= num" is because m is of type std::list while num is of type int.  It doesn't make sense to compare a list with an int, which is the real world equivalent of comparing a shopping list with 4, it just doesn't mean anything.  You may have intended "k <= num".

The line `cin >> s` is also an error, s isn't defined.

You also have a line `m.push_back(alpha[rand() % 100]);` that will be an error, m has a type of string while the using the [] operator on alpha will return a character, see code below for solution.

You use the modulus operator in two places, where you mod by 100.  If you want a character at a random index you should, in this case, do `alpha.substr((double) rand() / RAND_MAX * alpha.length(), 1)`.  Note that RAND_MAX is a constant that should be predefined, you shouldn't need to set it. I have a feeling what you're trying to accomplish in the inner loop looks like:

```
    string randomCharacter = alpha.substr((double) rand() / RAND_MAX * alpha.length(), 1)
    cout << randomCharacter << " " << endl;
    m.push_back(randomCharacter);
```

You are also missing a left brace in the code somewhere (may be due to copy-paste) which would be another reason it wouldn't compile.

If what you want is to be able to type in the terminal how many sequences of random characters followed by how many characters are in each sequence, you would want to re-write the inner loop to look like:

```
    string randomCharacters = "";
    for (int k = 0; k <= num; k++){
        string randomLetter = alpha.substr((double) rand() / RAND_MAX * alpha.length(), 1);
        cout << randomLetter << " " << endl;
        randomCharacters += randomLetter;
    }
    m.push_back(randomCharacters);
```

This will fill the list with strings filled with random characters from array alpha, which you can use later.  You can remove the cout if you don't want to see all the characters printed to the terminal as they are randomly chosen.

After your edit to the question:
The solution should look like:

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    int L;

    string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    vector<string> m;

    cout << "Give the number of lists: ";
    cin >> L;


    cout << "Give the number of elements for the lists: ";
    int num; 
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= L; i++){

        string randomCharacters = "";
        for (int k = 0; k < num; k++){
            string randomLetter = alpha.substr((double) rand() / RAND_MAX * alpha.length(), 1);
            randomCharacters += randomLetter;
        }
        m.push_back(randomCharacters);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "list" << (i+1)<< ": " << m[i] << endl;
    }
```

Note, this solution switched list for vector as it's simpler in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! Definitely have a better understanding of it now. Going to read over your comments a couple more times to let it to sink in.

Comment: You're welcome, it's no problem. I'm aware I am far from good at explaining things, so feel free to ask more questions. I'm new here, and just want to help some people during this quarantine.